# wait till the progressbar appears and disappears in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

working on an application where:

- case 1. The progress bar appears after 2 secs and disappears after 30 secs.
- case 2. sometimes the progress bar wont appear at all.

In case 2, wait for 2 secs and if progress bar does not appear then code should not check for invisibility.

I am trying with below script, which is not working

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this.progbar),2000).then(
    function() {
        browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(this.progbar),30000);
        return true;
},  function (error) {
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work because EC will throw an error if condition fails. So, you need to use `try... catch` construction.

```
try {
  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this.progbar), 2000).then(() => {
    browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(this.progbar), 30000).then(() => {
      return true;
    });
  });
} catch(e) {
  return false;
}
```